# UICollectionViewcell selectedBackgroundView bigger than cell

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I've implemented the `UICollectionView` with custom cells designed in xib. Now I'm trying to make the `selectedBackgroundView` bigger than original `cell`.

I've tried changing the cell's `clipsToBounds` to false (also in act of desperation contentView's, backgroundView's, selectedBackgroundView's), but with no effect.

Is it possible to have `selectedBackgroundViewBigger` than cell?

```
class MyCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    static let nibName = "MyCell"
    static let cellIdentifier = "MyCellIdentifier"

    private var oneTimeSetup = false

    @IBOutlet weak var image: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit() {
        let margin: CGFloat = -20

        let backgroundView = UIView.init(frame: self.bounds)
        backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.eventTypeCellBackground()
        self.backgroundView = backgroundView

        let biggerBounds = CGRect(x: margin, y: margin, width: self.bounds.width-margin*2, height: self.bounds.height-margin*2)
        let selectedBGView = UIView.init(frame: biggerBounds)
        selectedBGView.backgroundColor = UIColor.eventTypeCellBackgroundHighlited()
        self.selectedBackgroundView = selectedBGView

        self.clipsToBounds = false
        self.contentView.clipsToBounds = false
        self.backgroundView?.clipsToBounds = false
        self.selectedBackgroundView?.clipsToBounds = false
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        if !oneTimeSetup {
            label.textColor = UIColor.eventTypeLabelColor()
            oneTimeSetup = true
        }
    }
}
```